# Do I really need CTEs in PostgreSQL to aggregate two related tables?

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, common-table-expression

I have 3 tables, `coupons`, which are promotional coupons, `accounts` which are accounts that may or may not have a coupon that was used to signup, and `orders` which similarly has orders that may have used a coupon (or not).

I need to construct a query that returns all coupons with how many accounts were created by each, how many orders, and the amount of those orders (the sum). So far, the only way I found to make it work is using CETs with this query:

```sql
with accounts_by_coupon as (select accounts.coupon_id,
                                   count(accounts.*) as signups
                            from accounts
                            group by accounts.via),
     orders_by_coupon as (select orders.coupon_id,
                                 count(orders.*)    as sales,
                                 sum(orders.amonut) as revenue
                          from orders
                          group by orders.coupon_id)

select coupons.id,
       accounts_by_coupon.signups as signups,
       orders_by_coupon.sales     as sales,
       orders_by_coupon.revenue   as revenue

from coupons
         left join orders_by_coupon on coupons.id = orders_by_coupon.coupon_id
         left join accounts_by_coupon on coupons.id = accounts_by_coupon.coupon_id

group by coupons.id,
         accounts_by_coupon.signups,
         orders_by_coupon.sales,
         orders_by_coupon.revenue;
```

Is it possible to do it without CET? Is it possible to do it with subqueries in another way?

To make it easier to visualize, these are what the tables would look like:

`coupons`:

| id | code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10%OFF |
| 2 | 20%OFF |

`accounts`:

| id | username | coupon_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | johncarmack | 1 |
| 2 | setevewozniack | NULL |

`orders`:

| id | amount | coupon_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100.00 | 1 |
| 2 | 120.00 | NULL |
| 3 | 55.00 | 1 |
| 4 | 75.00 | 2 |

If you are wondering why I'm trying to not use CTE, it's mostly to see if I can get the query to be more Rails friendly.

Comment: Consider using window functions partitioning by the key of the respective tables. but I'm confused, you're grouping by accounts.via but then not selecting from it; so... you could have duplicates of a coupon id if multipe exist in a via.... confusing

Comment: You can move the CTE queries into a derived table `left join (... query from cte ...) as accounts_by_coupon  on ...`

Comment: Instead of aggregating the query could use two lateral queries -- that could have better performance, btw. But, I would guess they are not Rails-friendly as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
select   coupon_id
        ,code
        ,count(o.id)          as orders_per_coupon  
        ,sum(amount)          as revenue_per_coupon
        ,count(distinct a.id) as accounts_created_per_coupon
from     orders o left join accounts a using(coupon_id) join coupons c on c.id = o.coupon_id
group by coupon_id, code
```

| coupon_id | code | orders_per_coupon | revenue_per_coupon | accounts_created_per_coupon |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10%OFF | 2 | 155.00 | 1 |
| 2 | 20%OFF | 1 | 75.00 | 0 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GikQsPnm)